# Arrow contour detection with noise and random colors

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection

I want to detect the images of arrows in a certain game in the same order from left to right.

For example, **[left, up, down, right]** in the following case.

[image: bypassed_arrow_1]

The above arrows could be detected using color filter, erode, morphologyEx, etc. but not the following image.

[image: colorfull_arrow_1]

[image: colorfull_arrow_2]

[image: colorfull_arrow_3]

The color of this arrow changes every time.

I am new to opencv and would appreciate any help.

Comment: You could template match 4 times, once for each direction.

Comment: Continued: do canny edge detection and match the edge arrow templates with the edge image in cv2.matchTemplate() using an edge mask to ignore all but the edges.